# Does QGIS Recognize Annotation Feature Classes from File Geodatabase?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, annotation

My work has recently set up QGIS to access an Esri file geodatabase on a shared drive for my co-workers.

I have not used QGIS much, but I have encountered an issue where the annotation feature classes are displayed as a polygon instead of text. The geometry type of all the annotations are shown as 'MultiPolygon' when a vector layer from the geodatabase is added to QGIS.
When the annotations are added to ArcMap, they appear as they are meant to - as text.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: annotations_bad]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a QGIS limitation.

If you are loading the FileGDB into QGIS, it in turn is using GDAL, which in turn is using [ESRI's FileGDB API which does not support Annotation Feature Classes](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/13/file-geodatabase-api-details/) amongst other things.

You could ask ESRI to expand the functionality of their API...
Or consider seeing what the feasibility of hiring a developer *(or if you got the skills, attempt it yourself)* to implement that into the [OpenFileGDB driver for GDAL](http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_openfilegdb.html).

Often when loading the Annotation Feature Class into QGIS, it can make use of the attributes for labelling (font type, size - in metres or points, rotation, etc...) and you can just adjust the styling of the polygons to no fill and outline.

Comment: That makes sense, but labeling and changing the fill and outline does make annotations somewhat difficult to use for someone not familiar with the software.